# Composer doesn't find local vcs dependency

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project that depends on a local package which in itself depends on another local pakcage.

Project

```
{
...
  "repositories": [
    {
      "packagist": false
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "/path/to/local/package1"
    },
  ],  
  "require": {
    "local/package1": "dev-master"
  }
...
}
```

Package 1

```
{
...
  "repositories": [
    {
      "packagist": false
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "/path/to/local/package2"
    },
  ],  
  "require": {
    "local/package2": "dev-master"
  }
...
}
```

When I do a `composer install` on `package1`, everything works as expected, `packages2` is found and is installed. But when I do it on `project` it cannot find `package2` with this error:

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for local/package1 dev-master -> satisfiable by local/package1[dev-master].
    - local/package1 dev-master requires local/package2 dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

Comment: The problem is not that the recursive repository definitions are not allowed as mentioned in the answer below, but even when you copy the repository definition from the "child" to the "parent", it won't accept it and won't find it still. And now I am curious how they are going to explain this, that this is not a bug, but a feature, at least it's not finished functionality then imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Composer [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository):

> Repositories are only available to the root package and the
>   repositories defined in your dependencies will not be loaded. Read [the FAQ entry](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) if you want to learn why.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to add everything to project's json. It would've been great if composer added a `--recursive-repositories` option for cases like this. Solved.

Comment: Yes, composer isn't so flexible when it deals with recursion, there are some other pitfalls, e.g. no nested require-dev.

Comment: Recursing local repos is a complicated problem. It's not worth the hassle and time spend on implementing it, because working with local repos is and should be only temporary. The solution is to "publish" privately (Satis) or publicly (Packgist or clone). @estus Can you provide a use-case for the feature "nested require-dev".

Comment: I've dealt with dependency-heavy package not so long ago, some `require-dev` items were actually required for normal work, I ended up with browsing `suggest` entries, I believe it was something Laravel-related.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This sounds more like a "package definition gone in the wrong require section issue", than a real Composer "pitfall, e.g. no nested require-dev". I'm asking because, in order to improve Composer, it's important to identify the exact use-case or even better to have a composer.json to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It seems like it was some testing package, they are recommended to be added to `require-dev` for unobvious reason. It would be nice to have an option to force recursion anyway, though there's a risk to end up with enormous `vendor`.