# Composer local packages

Tags: composer-php

I can't get composer to work properly with local packages.

package A:

```
{
  "name": "package/A",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "../B"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "package/B": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

package B:

```
{
  "name": "package/B",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "../C"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "package/C": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

package C:

```
{
  "name": "package/C",
}
```

Now installing package B works fine and it resolves the package C properly.
Installing package A fails because it can not resolve the package C from the package B, which is the only dependency of package A.

I couldn't find anything about this @google, it looks like composer can't handle that kind of complexity in local packages. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Here is a small illustration for better understanding of this problem.
[image]

Comment: Recent duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270219/composer-doesnt-find-local-vcs-dependency/29270545#29270545

Comment: @estus Thank you for the hint. This is the exact same issue. I'm using "satis" now to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Composer doesn't load local repos recursively](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md).

1) You might declare dependencies for B and C in A. You have to redefine the dependencies in your composer.json. Here, this will add some more require and repository defines to composer.json of A.

2) Or you might setup a local Satis proxy, which serves your private packages.

Private or public publishing of the dependencies will resolve the situation.