# Composer SVN dependency error

Tags: svn, composer-php

I have some library classes in SVN with which I've been using Composer successfully.  But today I ran into this problem, where Composer believes it cannot find a matching package, even though it is there and Composer can find it in other circumstances.

Here is the composer.json for the 2 packages in question:

```
{
    "name": "clx/auth",
    "repositories": [ {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://svn.example.com/",
            "package-path": "Ldap"
        }
    } ],
    "require": { "clx/ldap": "dev-trunk" }
}

{
    "name": "clx/ldap",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://svn.example.com/",
            "package-path": "ClxMsg"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://svn.example.com/",
            "package-path": "ConfigIni"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "clx/clxmsg": "dev-trunk",
        "clx/configini": "dev-trunk"
    }
}
```

When I run install in the clx/ldap directory, the output looks like this and all is good.  Note that it *does* find `clx/clxmsg` and `clx/configini` without trouble:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing icecave/isolator (dev-develop fdf22e6)
    Cloning fdf22e670e7d10b51335083817ca0e8597c41168

  - Installing psr/log (dev-master 9e45edc)
    Cloning 9e45edca52cc9c954680072c93e621f8b71fab26

  - Installing cxj/phpsyslog (v1.1.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing clx/clxmsg (dev-trunk)
    Checking out /trunk/ClxMsg/@24831

  - Installing clx/configini (dev-trunk)
    Checking out /trunk/ConfigIni/@24831

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Yet when I go to the clx/auth package directory, it fails to find `clx/clxmsg` while satisfying `clx/ldap` -- the package above **where it just worked**!

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for clx/ldap dev-trunk -> satisfiable by clx/ldap[dev-trunk].
    - clx/ldap dev-trunk requires clx/clxmsg dev-trunk -> no matching package found.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there a bug in Composer doing recursive dependency resolution when using VCS sources in SVN?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same problem described in [Composer doesn't find local vcs dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270219/composer-doesnt-find-local-vcs-dependency).  I was unable to find the referenced post while searching but it nicely came up in the "Similar Questions" column on the right once I had typed in my problem description.

The short answer is "Composer does not do this with VCS packages."  The referenced question appears to use Git instead of SVN, but it makes no difference.

The explanation in the answers to the above referenced question, and in the provided link to the Composer FAQ (https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) describe why it does not work as expected.